# Square root sign has dotted line (PGF/TikZ + XeLaTeX). Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

I am encountering a number of problems using `XeLaTeX` and `PGF/TikZ`.  One concerns the  `spy` library and seems well-documented.  Today I have encountered another.  Here is a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
   \draw[thin, dotted] (0,0) -- node {$\sqrt{r_1 r_2}$} (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Compiling with `XeLaTeX` one sees that the line which extends the surd in the square root is also dotted (!):

[image: dotted line extending surd]

This does not happen with `PDFLaTeX`, for example:

[image]

Is there a workaround?

Comment: This is a [bug in PGF](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/136/) that has been fixed in the CVS version. (Xe)TeX’s rules somehow inherit the dashing style of PGF.

Answer (score 6):

You could add `solid` as an option to the node.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
   \draw[thin, dotted] (0,0) -- node[solid] {$\sqrt{r_1 r_2}$} (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed! That works!  (But this is surely not the intended behaviour, right?)

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill No, I wouldn't think so. Perhaps a bug in PGF's XeTeX driver, but I really have no clue about that stuff.